# Notification title not being shown in Android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am trying to take the title of the notification from the user to show when they reach the highest value and I did this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    minTitle1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minTitle1) ;
  maxTitle1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maxTitle1) ;


   submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                highestText = Integer.parseInt(highest.getText().toString().trim());
                minimumText = Integer.parseInt(minimum.getText().toString().trim());
                minTitle =minTitle1.getText().toString();
                maxTitle=maxTitle1.getText().toString();
            } catch(Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter numbers!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    countUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(highestText == 0 && minimumText == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter the target numbers!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {

                if (highestText == count+1 ) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "number");
                    builder.setContentTitle(maxTitle);
                    builder.setContentText("please be aware that you reached the maximum number");
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                    NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
                    managerCompat.notify(1, builder.build());
                }
```

For some reason the title does not show up with the notification. Am I missing something? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide more information? More code? Are you saying that `builder.setContentTitle(maxTitle);` is not working? You don't show where `maxTitle1` is assigned.

Comment: yes builder.setContentTitle(maxTitle); is not showing the title i took from user. i added more code to where its assigned

Comment: @mightyleen Can the user click on `countUp` without first clicking on `submit`?

Comment: Set a break point where `maxTitle` is assigned to see if it is getting a value. Set a break point where you set the notification title to see what the value of `maxTitle` is. Double check your `activity_main` layout to make sure that the ID `maxTitle1` is being assigned to the control where the user enters the title.

Comment: @akhilnair no they cant

Comment: can you show me what you mean ? do you want me to print the value ? @jimRhodes

Comment: @mightyleen Can you please add an image of how your notification currently looks like?

Comment: @mightyleen Are you running this on which android version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For android 8.0 and above you have to create a notification channel like this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
    String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

From your code it is clear that when your highest text becomes equal to count+1 your notification pops up but you are updating your maxtitle value in your submit button so it is not set to your current maxtitle value when your notification is shown.So
Add maxTitle=maxTitle1.getText().toString(); before your
builder.setContentTitle(maxTitle); to update your maxtitle on your countUp click.

```
         countUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(highestText == 0 && minimumText == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter the target numbers!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {

                if (highestText == count+1 ) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "number");
                    maxTitle=maxTitle1.getText().toString();
                    builder.setContentTitle(maxTitle);
                    builder.setContentText("please be aware that you reached the maximum number");
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                    NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
                    managerCompat.notify(1, builder.build());
                }
```

Comment: the notifications are working im struggling to show the title

Comment: what your maxtitle is??Is it a fix value??

Comment: no. im getting the value from the user

Comment: Insha Allah ta'aaa my updated answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

Something what is missing here is the creation of a channel

> Before you can deliver the notification on Android 8.0 and higher, you must register your app's notification channel with the system by passing an instance of NotificationChannel to createNotificationChannel()

```
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
    val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
        description = descriptionText
    }
    // Register the channel with the system
    val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
  }
}
```

> Because you must create the notification channel before posting any notifications on Android 8.0 and higher, you should execute this code as soon as your app starts. It's safe to call this repeatedly because creating an existing notification channel performs no operation.

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#kotlin)

Comment: i created a channel already. i couldnt post the code for it because it didnt allow me to put more code